# Play Framework Java - Display htm file stored on local server

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

Hello Stackoverflow community !

I am working with the Play Framework 2.1.1 using Java.

Ideally I would like that, when the user click on a link in the top menu (defined by a Navbar) he gets redirected to a file stored in an internal server. The file path is of type "*file:///R:/PUBLIC/Name/myfile.htm*", and the file contains a picture.

Unfortunately this doesn't work (when I click a blank page opens, titled "unknown") and I can't really figure out why... I have no error, just the blank page.

Here is the link in the top menu:

```
        <li><a href="@routes.Application.guideline()" target="_blank">@Messages.get("general.guidelines")</a></li>
```

Then here is the guideline() function in the controller Application:

```
public static Result guideline() {

    Guideline guidelineLink = Guideline.find.select("*").where().eq("id", 1).findUnique();
    if(guidelineLink.link == null){
        return ok(views.html.display.createError.render());
    }else{      
        return redirect(guidelineLink.link);
    }
}
```

I retrieve the path to the file in the database, this works, I have been testing it using a standard "http://...." url. The link retrieved is the path above-mentionned.

Of course I have tried to simply open the file by copy/pasting it in my browser and it works. I also tried to change the extension to .html, or to remove the "file:///" at the beginning but without success. I also found nothing on the internet, my good friend Google failed me on this one !

Thank you all for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a blank page because of security reasons. In [RFC1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) you read that:

> The file URL scheme is used to designate files accessible on a
>   particular host computer. This scheme, unlike most other URL schemes,
>   does not designate a resource that is universally accessible over the
>   Internet. (...)
>
> The file URL scheme is unusual in that it does not specify an Internet
>   protocol or access method for such files; as such, its utility in
>   network protocols between hosts is limited.

Image that browsers were able to open any file on your local machine. It would open new ways of exploiting as nothing would prevent remote pages from accessing your local data. Of course, your browser can open local file but it's just an additional feature to basic application and that works only if you initialise the open action manually.

To achieve what you want you can:

- put the file in your project public resources
- load the file's content on the server side (note that it must be granted with access rights to this resource) and then return it with a custom response

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
What I don't understand is that at this location the file is accessible to any user in the network, so why not to the browser ? I mean I am not the one who created the file and put it there, however I can open it from my computer, what's the difference ?
Sorry if this is supposed to be obvious :-(

Comment: I misunderstood your problem at first. Your comment made it clear so I updated my post.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is much more clear now :-)